# Why can we chain flatMap to UserDefaults.standard.data

Tags: ios, swift, swiftyuserdefaults

In an article about UserDefaults in iOS development, I saw a code snippet where flatMap is chained to UserDefaults.standard.data like below:

```
self.isReadStatuses = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "isReadStatuses")
      .flatMap { try? JSONDecoder().decode([URL: Bool].self, from: $0) } ?? [:]
```

Does anyone know Why can we use .flatMap here?

Comment: `flatMap()` can be used on `Data` instance, no? That's why then. Question about what it transforms that is another question and other test you can do.

Comment: @Larme it's rather the `flatMap` of Optional, not of `Data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey:)` returns `Data?` - an `Optional<Data>`, and [`Optional` has a `.flatMap` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap).

Specifically here, the `flatMap` closure gets a non-optional `Data`, and attempts to decode it returning another `[URL:Bool]?` (also, an optional because of `try?`).

Comment: Hi @New Dev, thanks for the explanation and share the link to the documentation about using .flatMap method on an optional. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I can guess why are you confused, although im not sure. I think you think that `.map` (and it's brothers, `.flatMap` and `.compactMap`) can only be used on Collections (e.g. an Array). That is completely wrong. `.map` (and the other 2) have a meaning of *transformation*, not iterating through an collection/array. So while they can be used on arrays, they have many more use-cases as well.
You can read more about differences between those 3 kinds of `map` [here](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/map-flatmap-and-compactmap/).
In the code you showed, the author of that blog post has used `.flatMap` with intention of *transforming* an `Optional<Data>` value (aka Data?) to `[URL: Bool]` which is the value he wants.

```
let udData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "isReadStatuses")

// Short way:
let isReadStatuses1 = udData.flatMap {
    try? JSONDecoder().decode([URL: Bool].self, from: $0)
} ?? [:]

// Long way:
let isReadStatuses2: [URL: Bool]
if let data = udData {
    isReadStatuses2 = (try? JSONDecoder().decode([URL: Bool].self, from: data)) ?? [:]
} else {
    isReadStatuses2 = [:]
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mahdi BM, thanks for the explanation. I was confused with using flatMap on an optional data, and I did not know that an optional had the flatMap method. You explanation does clear my confusion.

Comment: Basically, __anything__ could have a `map` function. You could create your own structure and make a `map` function for it as well. The thing is though, `map` in  programming, even in other languages means _transformation_, so it is conventional to use `map` _only_ where you want to enable your type to be easily transformable, and not in other places.